# Spark Job failing with out of memory exception

Tags: apache-spark

- Spark job failing with

> Exception in thread "main"
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: Can you share the code as well ?

Comment: Hey Shankar.. Below is the code that am trying to run

Answer (score 0):

Spark was by default taking 1g of driver memory. I increased driver memory to 4g.